# Ansible - how to conditionally change an item in the list

Tags: ansible

I have two lists:

```
        "combo_all": [
        [
            null,
            "3",
            "210
        ],
        [
            "r0004",
            "65",
            "212"
        ]
```

and

```
        "zone_name_list": [
        {
            "dns_zone_id": 10423,
            "name": "212.18.172.in-addr.arpa."
        },
        {
            "dns_zone_id": 10424,
            "name": ""210.18.172.in-addr.arpa."."
        }
```

How can I replace the third item in the "combo_all" (first list) by the "dns_zone_id" number (from the second list) whenever the first octet from the "name" matches the third item from the first list (210, 212)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the dictionary *octet1_id*

```yaml
  dns_zone_id: "{{ zone_name_list|map(attribute='dns_zone_id') }}"
  octet1: "{{ zone_name_list|map(attribute='name')
                            |map('split', '.')
                            |map('first') }}"
  octet1_id: "{{ dict(octet1|zip(dns_zone_id)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  octet1_id:
    '210': 10424
    '212': 10423
```

Then create a list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        combo_id: "{{ combo_id|d([]) + [item[:-1] + [octet1_id[item[-1]]]] }}"
      loop: "{{ combo_all }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  combo_id:
    - [null, '3', 10424]
    - [r0004, '65', 10423]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    combo_all:
      - [ null, "3", "210"]
      - [ "r0004", "65", "212"]
    zone_name_list:
      - {dns_zone_id: 10423, name: 212.18.172.in-addr.arpa.}
      - {dns_zone_id: 10424, name: 210.18.172.in-addr.arpa.}

    dns_zone_id: "{{ zone_name_list|map(attribute='dns_zone_id') }}"
    octet1: "{{ zone_name_list|map(attribute='name')
                              |map('split', '.')
                              |map('first') }}"
    octet1_id: "{{ dict(octet1|zip(dns_zone_id)) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dns_zone_id
    - debug:
        var: octet1
    - debug:
        var: octet1_id

    - set_fact:
        combo_id: "{{ combo_id|d([]) + [item[:-1] + [octet1_id[item[-1]]]] }}"
      loop: "{{ combo_all }}"
    - debug:
        var: combo_id|to_yaml
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and the (working) solution you have provided!

Answer (score 3):

In general, Ansible isn't a great tool for *modifying* data structures. You can get close to what you want by creating a **new** variable with your desired content by doing something like this:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    "combo_all": [
      [ null, "3", "210" ],
      [ "r0004", "65", "212" ]
      ]
    "zone_name_list": [
        {
            "dns_zone_id": 10423,
            "name": "212.18.172.in-addr.arpa."
        },
        {
            "dns_zone_id": 10424,
            "name": "210.18.172.in-addr.arpa."
        }
      ]

  tasks:
    - vars:
        new_combo_all: []
        prefix: "{{ item[1]['name'].split('.')[0] }}"
      set_fact:
        new_combo_all: >
          {{ new_combo_all + [[item[0][0], item[0][1], item[1]['dns_zone_id']]] }}
      loop: "{{ combo_all | product(zone_name_list) }}"
      when: prefix == item[0][2]

    - debug:
        var: new_combo_all
```

This will set `new_combo_all` to:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "new_combo_all": [
        [
            null,
            "3",
            10424
        ],
        [
            "r0004",
            "65",
            10423
        ]
    ]
}
```

It works by iterating over the cartesian product of `combo_all` and `zone_name_list`, selecting only those pairs for which the `name` prefix octet is equal to the third member of the sublist from `combo_all`, and uses this to generate the `new_combo_all` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and the working solution you have provided! I've green marked Vladimir's solution since I personally find it easier to read.